# Advice on Buffering keyboard input (C++)

Tags: c++, keyboard

I am trying to use the space bar to pause my game, but don't know how to just toggle my pause bool.

I have a BYTE key[] that I use to check my key state (& 0x80).

I can't seem to find the right way to toggle the key though, ending up in some wonky behavior on my pause (it is a pong clone, so the ball either slows down, pauses, or does nothing).

I would greatly appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

EDIT:
I am writing a Win 32 app, using Direct2D.

Comment: What keyboard API are you using?

Comment: Are you saying that your boolean is a single bit and you want to toggle that bit?  Maybe you should show us a little bit of code so we can better guess what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Key presses are platform specific.  You'll need to use platform specific functions to determine when a key is pressed or *receive notification that a key was pressed*.

In order for StackOverflow users to help you further, you will have to add the platform and compiler version (tools) to your post.

Console programs will have a different process for detecting key presses than windowing programs.